# How to input hexcodes/escape sequences through stdin into a program that reads from it twice?

Tags: terminal, hex, escaping, stdin

I have a C binary that,

1. prints out an integer (let's call it modifiedInteger)
2. takes input from stdin
3. given `modifiedInteger = secretMathFunction(originalInteger)`, if input is equal to originalInteger, it proceeds, if not, it exits
4. reads from stdin into a buffer (that I'm ultimately trying to overflow with shellcode)

When I try sending hexcodes ("\xFF\x00\x00"... etc) into a buffer via my terminal's stdin, it goes into memory as the ASCII representation (I could tell before I even checked gdb because of how much longer it made the input). However, when I send hexcodes via "echo -e" or Python print, it interprets the escape characters correctly, but I don't know how to do this such that I can input twice. I use kitty terminal, so some fancy remote control stuff is probably possible if this isn't an easy thing to do.

Thanks